# Чи походить слово "безпека" від назви слов'янського божества Пека?

Tags: етимологія

У харківському політесі на курсі, якщо я не забув точну назву, "Охорона праці та безпека життєдіяльності" нам були подані відомості щодо етимології слова [*безпека*](http://um.in.ua/s/bezpeka). Нібито слово походить від назви слов'янського слов'янського хтонічного бога [*Пека*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D0%BA_(%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3)), через заперечення приставкою `без-` притаманних божеству якостей, ворожих та шкідливих людині.

Нажаль у зовнішньому Інтернеті мені не вдається знайти ані підтвердження, ані спростування цієї гіпотези. Можливо шановній спільноті відомі поважні джерела, які прояснюють етимологію наведеного слова

*Чи походить слово *безпека* від назви слов'янського божества *Пека*?*

Answer (score 12):

Слово *безпека* походить від старослов'янського кореня `*peča`, що означає **«турбота»**.
Є спорідненим зі словами [*опіка*](http://sum.in.ua/s/opika), [*піклуватися*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pikluvatysja), [*печаль*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pechalj), *пекло* і навіть *пекти*.

[Етимологічний словник української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) (том 1, літери «А—Г») надає таку етимологію:

[image: слово безпека у словнику]
<sub>(перепрошую за використання скріншоту; не зміг знайти цього словника у текстовому вигляді)</sub>

Той самий «Етимологічний словник української мови» (том 4, літери «Н—П») надає ще більш детальне пояснення до слова **«піклуватися»**:

[image: слово піклуватися у словнику]

У [словнику ЮНВЕС](http://www.endic.ru/semenov/Bespechn-466.html) те саме слово виводиться із `pѣkjъ`, а [словник Дрофа](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Bespechn-1451.html) вказує, що `пека` + суфікс `-j-`  + `kj > ч`.

Стосовно назви божества Пек, той самий словник дає таку етимологію:

[image: слово пек у словнику]

Comment: Цікаво, а `спекатись` пов'язано з цими всіма словами?

Answer (score 6):

*Безпека* [утворене](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=163) від того ж кореня, що й *піктися (про когось)*, *опікуватися*, *опіка*, тобто від кореня *пек-*, як у [*пекти (печу)*](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=329). Цей корінь праіндоевропейський, ***peku̯-** «варити, готувати», та утворені від нього слова є практично в усіх давніх та сучасних індоевропейських мовах, від індійських до германських, від перської до албанської, від санскрита до давньогрецької та латини, тому *слов'янське* божество Пек тут зовсім ні до чого. Та між *безпека* та *Пек* є зв’язок, оскільки Пек — бог пекла, то скоріше за все його ім’я теж походить від цього самого кореня *пек-*, тобто ці слова походять від одного кореня, а не одне слово від иншого.